# Exibir somente diretórios não vazios com o comando ls

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Olá,

Sou iniciante em Ubuntu e gostaria de saber se há alguma maneira de exibir somente diretórios que contenham subdiretórios ou arquivos na linha de comando. Se eu digito somente `ls`, aparecem diretórios, arquivos executáveis e não executáveis agrupados pela cor. Gostaria que aparecessem somente os diretórios não-vazios. Obrigado!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -not -empty -type d
```

Onde `.` é o caminho para o diretório que você quer listar, nesse caso aí ele está procurando no diretório atual.

Answer (score 1):

Pode usar os seguintes comandos:

```
find ~/meuDiretorio -not -empty -type d -ls
```

O comando acima vai listar apenas as pastas que possui algum conteúdo.

O comando `find` serve para pesquisar pastas e arquivos, a opção `-not` significa negação, neste caso é para inverter o retorno da opção `-empty` que é para especificar arquivos ou pastas vazias, e a opção `-type` é para especificar um tipo que deseja, o tipo definido foi diretórios através da opção `d` passada para `-type`, e ela seria como um tipo de filtro, e finalmente a opção `-ls` que é responsável por obter algumas informações a mais, e neste contexto ela é uma opção do comando `find`, você pode remover ela se desejar ver apenas os diretórios não vazios.

O caractere `~` indica a sua pasta home, exemplo `/home/usuario`, você pode mudar se quiser.

Fontes:
How can I list only non-empty files using ls?: https://superuser.com/questions/191889/how-can-i-list-only-non-empty-files-using-ls
Manual do comando find: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html